# Reasons for segmentation fault at different places in different run

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault

I am enumerating reasons why segmentation fault can occur at different place in different run assuming no randomization in C++ code. Such segmentation fault are hard to debug. On most occasions it occurs for me in allocation of big memories and system running out memory.

Comment: Because you are addressing memory you aren't supposed to. Fix your design.

Comment: @kunal How this translate segmentation fault at different place in different run? Seg fault will always occur at same place - assuming  same input and no randomization.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)

> A segmentation fault (often shortened to segfault), bus error, or access violation is generally an attempt to access memory that the CPU cannot physically address. It occurs when the hardware notifies an operating system about a memory access violation. The OS kernel will in response usually perform some corrective action, such as sending the offending process a signal, terminating it, or causing it to dump core.

So, you are definitely doing something in your code because of which it is trying to access memory that it is not allowed to. And if segmentation faults always occurred at the same place, life would have been so much more easier.